# Node.js AWS S3 Hangs Indefinitely on Large Number of Image File getObject Requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an app requesting up to few hundred image files from Amazon S3 at a time. The files are requested in sequence using nested promises (so it is not an issue with some limitation on the number of requests per second or the amount of data that can be transferred at once), and everything goes fine up to a little over 100 files. However, S3 hangs indefinitely thereafter. How do I fix this? See relevant code below.

```
function one_by_one(objects_array, iterator, callback) {
    let start_promise = objects_array.reduce(function (prom, object) {
        return prom.then(function () {
            return iterator(object);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve()); // initial
    if(callback){
        start_promise.then(callback);
    }else{
        return start_promise;
    }
}

let grabImage = function(image){
      params = {Bucket: 'partpics', Key: image};
      let getObjectPromise = s3.getObject(params).promise();
      return getObjectPromise.then(function(data) {
          console.log('Success');
          res.imageBuffers.push(data.Body);
          bufferTemp = res.imageBuffers;
          console.log('res.imageBuffers index: ',res.imageBuffers.length-1);
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });

};
let myCallback = function() {
  next();
}
one_by_one(res.insertThis.Image,grabImage,myCallback);
```

Comment: Could you replace the S3 GetObject function by a simple curl-like call (http get) of some web resource to be sure that your promise code/framework is not the problem?

Comment: That is definitely not the issue, because I had the same problem before I used any promises. I thought the issue might be too many parallel requests, thus the promises. But that wasn't the problem apparently.

Comment: I tried a different approaching using the request-promise module to get data from AWS Cloudfront. It still stops at exactly the same place Therefore I have conclusively determined that this is not an AWS S3 issue, but rather a Node (or possibly OS) issue.

Comment: FYI I did a quick test with node v6.9.2 with 250x S3 objects, each 64KB in size, and I was able to get all of them successfully using either async.each (in parallel) or async.eachSeries (serially). I then tested with your code (against the same 250x 64KB objects) and that worked fine too.

Comment: How strange. It doesn't seem to be my OS either because the same thing happens when I deploy it to Heroku and run from there.

Comment: By the way if you can provide info on what your scenario is and will number of images grow with time? I would be able to propose a solution for it.

Comment: Scenario: I am creating a CSV-to-PDF label maker. PDFKit (https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit) creates the PDF and requires the images on each label to be local when it accesses them (i.e. I cannot give a remote URL).

The number of images does not grow with time (mostly). One may be added manually from time to time.

The app works wonderfully (and faster) if I save all the images to its public assets folder directly. But this essentially breaks my Git repo once I push to Git and/or Heroku, as Git creates objects so large that pushes hang indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I resolved the issue by moving the app from Heroku (which required Git pushes, therefore causing the large Git objects problem when image files were saved locally) to Digital Ocean (which does not require Git, thereby enabling local saving of the images). As such, AWS S3 is also now out of the picture. In addition, this provided the additional benefit of making the app's PDF generation much, much faster.